# Bounded random walk

Tags: random, recursion

I have a random walk algorithm that I want to implement, but I am getting a recursion depth issue. I am making a list of points that `Z` particles can be in over the domain $(-L/2,L/2)$. I am using a double `For` loop that will generate the values for the points of the different particles given this domain. The code is:

```
    Remove["Global`*"]
    Z = 3;
    NMAX = 3;
    l = 1;
    L = 100;
    x[0, i_] = 0;
    For[i = 0, i <= Z, i++,

    For[n = 1, n <= NMAX, n++,

    If[Abs[x[n - 1, i] + l Cos[2 π RandomReal[]]] >= L/2, 
    x[n, i] := x[n, i] = x[n - 1, i] - l Cos[2 π RandomReal[]], 
    x[n, i] := x[n, i] = x[n - 1, i] + l Cos[2 π RandomReal[]]]]]

    Table[x[n, i], {n, 0, NMAX}, {i, 0, Z}] // TableForm
```

$l$ is the uniform step that the particle will take and the `If` statement makes sure that the `x` position is assigned such that the value is within the domain. I would like to extend this also to `y` coordinates but that is something I will tackle after I can work this kink out.

I also started the list of particles (at time $n=0$) at position (0,0). The issue I am running into is that while the position for all (3) particles, starts off at 0 and then the first time step is shown but after that the out put is `x[2,i]` and `x[3,i]`. It works for the first time step, but not for any subsequent time steps. The error that I get is:

> Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.

I tried setting the recursion limit to 4000, since I found this somewhere else and it works for some problems, but ...

1. I am not sure what setting the recursion limit does.
2. It didn't work for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try with l1 = 1; l2 = 100; and accordingly the formation of formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Random walks are easy to implement with *Mathematica*. I think you would find many examples on this site if you were to search on "random walk". To implement the walk you describe, it just as easy to implement the 2D version you are aiming for as the 1D one, so the 2D walk is what I will discuss here.

First. Nested `For`-loops are not the way to go. I will use [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) which is a commonly used functional looping construct. I will also use recursion to handle the bounds constraint, but in a way the will not lead to uncontrolled recursion.

Second. I will use a divide-and-conquer implementation strategy. I break the problem in three parts.

1. A function `nextPt`, which given the current point and the radius of the disk of possible next locations returns the next point of the walk. `nextPt` uses recursion to implement the boundary constraint.
2. A function `walk`, which given the starting point, the radius of the disk of possible next locations, and the number of steps to be taken returns a list of points comprising the walk.
3. A function `walkPlot`, which given a list made by `walk` produces a visualization of the walk. The stating point is shown as a red dot and ending point is shown as a blue dot. `walkPlot` will take additional options which will be passed on to `Graphics`, so the look of the plot can be modified to suit other needs. (The option handling could certainly be improved, but I thought adding the extra code required would distract from the main point of this answer.)

You may not need `walkPlot` for your work. You may just need first two functions to generated data for any further processing you have in mind.

```
With[{w = 10., h = 8.}, 
  With[{bounds = Rectangle[{-w/2., -h/2.}, {w/2., h/2}]}, 
    nextPt[ pt_, r_] := 
      Block[{nxt = pt + r {Cos[#], Sin[#]}&[RandomReal[2. π]]},
        If[RegionMember[bounds, nxt], Return[nxt]];
        nextPt[pt, r]];
    walk[start : {_Real, _Real}, r_Real?Positive, steps_Integer?Positive] :=
      NestList[nextPt[#, r] &, start, steps]; 
    walkPlot[path_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
      Graphics[{
        Line[path],
        Red, Disk[First[path], Scaled[.015]],
        Blue, Disk[Last[path], Scaled[.015]]},
        opts,
        PlotRange -> Transpose[List @@ bounds],
        Frame -> True]]]
```

Note the following:

- [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html), a fairly recent addition to *Mathematica*, is used to test whether or not a candidate point lies within the boundary rectangle.
- The `walk` function is extremely simple in *Mathematica*'s functional style. It also has much better performance than `For`.

Now let's run three experiments with the following code.

```
SeedRandom[2];
Column[Table[walkPlot[walk[{0., 0.}, 2., 150], ImageSize -> Medium], 3]]
```

[image: walks]

## Update

I have corrected an error in the function `nextPt`. The updated version
correctly generates steps of magnitude `r`.

Comment: `Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2]]` is a quicker, trig-free way of getting a uniformly distributed random unit vector.

Comment: @J.M. Your suggestion relies on mathematics that is beyond me. I merely adopted and adapted the method the OP had already chosen.

Comment: @m_goldberg I will look into NestList as an alternative and thank you for the detailed and outlined response. As J. M. mentioned I was actually using the RandomVariate command in a different approach where I made a list and using the Accumulate ( and If) function to append to an empty list if the number was within the bounds.

Comment: @m_goldberg I also want to do some analysis of the given data. Say I want to run this 10,000 times for each distinct particle. Then I would want to be able to average over the x values of all particles at a given time step for example I wrote some code using the `Do` function. 
`Do[s[i_]:=s[i]=walk[{0,0},1.,400.],{i,1,10,000}]` which just takes a few seconds to do but accessing the elements in the list takes an atrocious amount of time. Is there anyway you can think of implementing this in a way that makes it faster?

Comment: @phandaman. Do not ask a new question in a comment of answer.

Comment: @phandaman. Your `walk` function can not be the same as the one I posted. It takes a different argument sequence, so I can't reproduce what you doing. I would guess that what you want is something like `results = Table[walk[{0., 0.}, 1., 400], 10000]; {xMeans, yMeans} = Transpose[Mean /@ results];` Do not run this with the large numbers 400 and 10000 before trying and verifying that your version of this suggest works with small numbers, say, 4 and 10.

Comment: @m_goldberg It works exactly like I'd want it to. Unfortunately, I ultimately have to take a sample size of `400` and `10000`. Using `Timing` I can see that as I add a zero to either `4` or `10`, my initial data sizes per your suggestion, the amount of time required increases by a factor of 10. I can ask this as a separate question If you'd prefer since I have already gone outside of the scope of the original question.

Comment: @m_goldberg actually the `Transpose` of results gets me to where I want. I want the average position of all `400` particles at time step `n`. Thanks so much for your help though.

Comment: I like this a lot, I made a modification in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111843/9490) to make it work with version 9.0 and added an animation there as well.