# Random walk in limited range

Tags: random

```
m = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 
1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}};
m2 = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 
1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}};
Manipulate[
 Do[
  m[[n]] = m[[n]] + RandomChoice[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}}];
  , {n, 10}];
 Do[
 m2[[n]] = m2[[n]] + RandomChoice[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}}];
   , {n, 10}];
Show[ListPlot[m, PlotStyle -> Red]
  , ListPlot[m2, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.03]}]]
, {n, 1, 20}]
```

This is pseudo-randomwalk. I want to plot in only square (0,0),(100,0),(0,100),(100,100). Please teach me the random walk in limited range.

Comment: Here are links to learn from, have you been there? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+walk

Comment: Do you think it is a duplicate question? [Bounded random walk](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108484/5478)

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry.

Comment: As I see it, the only necessary modification in m_goldberg's code for your purposes is to modify the definition for `nxt`: `nxt = pt + RandomChoice[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}}]`

Comment: @J.M. - also a small modification of the bounds, so that the rectangle is centered on the point `{50,50}` rather than `{0,0}`

Comment: m_goldberg's code cannot rum. Help me.

Comment: RegionMember not supported in version 9. What should I change code?

Comment: You should have mentioned that you were on version 9 to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This modification of m_goldberg's [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108531/9490) should work on version 9.0

```
nextPt[pt_, r_, bounds_] := 
  Block[{nxt = pt + r {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &[RandomReal[2. π]]}, 
   If[And @@ Thread[bounds[[1]] <= nxt <= bounds[[2]]], Return[nxt]];
   nextPt[pt, r, bounds]];
walk[start : {_Real, _Real}, range : {_Real, _Real}, r_Real?Positive, 
   steps_Integer?Positive] := 
  Module[{bounds}, bounds = {start - range/2, start + range/2};
   NestList[nextPt[#, r, bounds] &, start, steps]];
walkAnimation[path_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  ListAnimate[
   Table[
    Graphics[{Line[path[[;; n]]],
      Red, Disk[First[path], Scaled[.015]],
      Blue, Disk[path[[n]], Scaled[.015]]},
     opts, Frame -> True],
    {n, Length@path}], 10];

walkAnimation[walk[{50., 50.}, {100., 100.}, 5., 200], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help, welcome to the site, take the [tour], come back if you have other troubles, and try to answer questions when you can.  Next time you have a question, if you are still using a previous version of *Mathematica*, be sure to include that in the quesiton, as it can help get to the pertinent info more quickly.